# Python Function: Getting NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Tags: python, function

Created a function in Python to get the sum of the variables but getting the error

```py
def find_sum(*numbers):
  result = 0
  for num in numbers:
    result = result + num
print("Sum = ", result)

find_sum(1,2,3)
```

ERROR

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2e6d0015b7d8> in <cell line: 5>()
      3   for num in numbers:
      4     result = result + num
----> 5 print("Sum = ", result)
      6 
      7 find_sum(1,2,3)

NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

This function should print `Sum = 6`

Comment: your `print` is not part of the function (due to indentation)

Comment: A much better pattern is for the find_sum function to simply return the result, instead of printing it, and for the caller of find_sum to print the returned value, as needed.

Comment: To avoid these problems, use an IDE such as Pycharm or visual studio

Comment: Thank you all!! the function is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the scope of the result variable. In your code, the variable result is defined within the find_sum function, but you're trying to print it outside the function. This causes a NameError because the result variable is not accessible outside the function's scope.

To fix the error, you need to move the print statement inside the find_sum function. Here's the corrected code:

```
def find_sum(*numbers):
  result = 0
  for num in numbers:
    result = result + num
  print("Sum =", result)

find_sum(1, 2, 3)
```

---

Also voted to close this.

Comment: It seems uncool to both answer and vote to close. Why have you done that?

Comment: @tchrist I believe it is better to have answered questions than unanswered ones, even if they are bad questions. Orthogonally, bad questions should be closed. Coolness is irrelevant. You can link to a meta post if this was ever discussed.